# Alexa skill will not install via voice

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa skill that's been published and in the alexa app store for some time. Recently, the ability for users to install this skill by voice no longer works. I noticed this within the last 7 days.

Now when a user asks 'Alexa, enable shop clerk', they hear the message:

> "If you'd like to enable this skill, you can do so by finding it in the Skills section of your Alexa app."

Previously (and for virtually all skills I've tried) the normal response is to install and enable the skill.

Has anyone seen this behavior or have an idea of how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the following info from the Amazon Alexa team:

> > Thanks for your patience. To ensure the high-quality and accuracy of the voice-enablement feature for skills, we are making improvements to the feature. During this time, the feature will not apply to all skills.

Basically, they're saying "yeah, it doesn't work for your skill anymore."

I followed up with them and they acknowledge that it is a challenge for us but that they can give no information as to why this happened to us, how we can resolve it, or when (or even if) it will ever be resolved.